# Gravitational and cosmological redshifts

Tags: general-relativity, redshift

Light that we receive today from a far-off galaxy originated in the past when universe was much smaller. If we approximate the universe to be a sphere, light originated from a much smaller sphere with a much lower gravitational potential and has traveled far off to us. Because of lower gravitational potential, time was moving much slower (than today):- so a time period that originated as T (say) appears more than T explaining the redshift. Maybe, the universe is not expanding any longer or not expanding at the rate it is thought to: because at least a part of the redshift is explained by the gravitational contribution above. Please clarify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "If we approximate the universe to be a sphere, light originated from a much smaller sphere with a much lower gravitational potential " This is wrong. The observations we we have of the universe cannot be modeled as a three dimensional sphere  expanding in time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to compare the rate of flow of time at different times. The difference in gravitational potential is relevant for different positions.

Comment: But if you are far off from a massive sphere, time will flow faster at your end.